# Stopping execution in a method to call another method then continue

Tags: objective-c

In objective-c what is the best way to handle this situation. In all my calls to a remote API, I need to be sure I have token first. I would rather not check for the token before each call if possible.

```
DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS FOR EVERY API CALL!
#if (token) { 
   makeGetForTweetsRequestThatRequiresToken
 }
```

If I need a token, maybe it expired, that call might take some time to return so I need to wait for it to return, before the next API call is made. Is it possible to do the following?

```
[thing makeGetForTweetsRequestThatRequiresToken];


-(void)makeGetForTweetsRequestThatRequiresToken {
      if(nil == token) {

         // make another API call to get a token and save it
         // stop execution of the rest of this method until the
         // above API call is returned.

      } 

      //Do the makeGetForTweetsRequestThatRequiresToken stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your token API will have a callback. You can register a block to handle that callback to your TweetsRequest API:

```
typedef void (^TokenRequestCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSString *token);

-(void) requestTokenCompletionHandler:(TokenRequestCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    //Call your token request API here.
    //If get a valid token, for example error==nil
    if (!error) {
        completionHandler(YES,token);
    } else {
        completionHandler(NO,token);
    }
}
```

And in your tweet request:

```
-(void)makeGetForTweetsRequestThatRequiresToken {
  if(nil == token) {

     // make another API call to get a token and save it
     // stop execution of the rest of this method until the
     // above API call is returned.
     [tokenManager requestTokenCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSString *token){
         if (success) {
           //Do the makeGetForTweetsRequestThatRequiresToken stuff

         } else {
           NSLog(@"Token Error");
         }
     }];
  } else {
    //You have a token, just Do the makeGetForTweetsRequestThatRequiresToken stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: you have completionHandler(YES,token); twice?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Edited! Thank you